# Database events and perl

Tags: perl, postgresql

I have a Perl script that queries the database to see if any new rows added to database or not and if there is a new row i want to do something based on the values of it's columns. I want to know is there a way to do not select all rows in the database every time? Is there something like a hook in PSQL that can execute a Perl sub every time a new row becomes available?

Comment: Are you using PL/Perl or just some Perl script which connects to the database through DBI?

Comment: No i dont use PL/Perl, i use a simple Perl script that connect to the database.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there something like a hook in PSQL that can execute a Perl sub every time a new row becomes available?

### Option 1: PL/Perl

You could use [PL/Perl](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html) triggers for this.

You can't run a Perl sub from your existing program, you need to supply a PL/Perl procedure, and it can't invoke code outside PostgreSQL directly. What you *can* do is use inter-process communication (network sockets, signals, etc) to talk to an external program. Invoking external commands via `system()` from PL/Perl isn't a great idea, though.

### Option 2: `LISTEN` / `NOTIFY`

Have a simple PL/PgSQL trigger that does a `NOTIFY` whenever a change occurs, either sending the details via the notify payload (newer Pg and DBI versions) or inserting details into a table for your client to query. Have a PL/Perl program stay connected to the DB and `LISTEN` for that event. When the event comes in, use the notify payload to decide what to do, or query the table for details.

Search for "listen" and "notify" to learn more about this approach. This is usually the best choice.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I had a similar problem and solved it by using LISTEN / NOTIFY like Craig Ringer suggested, but I did it by using DBI directly.

There is a nice function in DBD::Pg that one can use to listen to Postgres notifications. This is from the DBD::Pg CPAN docs:

```
$dbh->do("LISTEN abc");
$dbh->do("LISTEN def");

## Hang around until we get the message we want
LISTENLOOP: {
  while (my $notify = $dbh->pg_notifies) {
    my ($name, $pid, $payload) = @$notify;
    print qq{I received notice "$name" from PID $pid, payload was "$payload"\n};
    ## Do something based on the notice received
  }
  $dbh->ping() or die qq{Ping failed!};
  $dbh->commit();
  sleep(5);
  redo;
}
```